# How to cancel REST HTTP request in Java?

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jersey, microservices

When cancelling the request, for example POST request using request.abort() or cancel(), that only suspend the client from waiting for response. In server side the command is not stopped. The data will be posted in the database. How to cancel the request itself from client ?

Comment: In general: you can't. Once the request reaches the server you are out of options. Unless your server explicitly offers and implements the option to send a second request that can cancel / interrupt other / previously submitted long running tasks.

Comment: In reactive spring there is an option to cancel the request using webflux. It will cancel the execution on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do anything once call is made to server. You can create another request which will undo the changes made on the server side.